# How can I do a secure reinstallation on an android device?

Tags: android

I want to reinstall the rom on my android device. I like to assume that the system is infected when I do a reinstallation of any device, so if it was really infected and I haven't noticed, I'm on the secure side.

I'm not very familiar with the android internals. What would be the steps somebody would have to do, after he had ran a malicious application and granted root privileges?

Comment: Which ROM do you want to install? And what device do you have?

Comment: @Tie-fighter CyanogenMod-7 and Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: 1. Is the phone rooted?
2. What type of device is it?
3. What if any cause for thinking there is malicious activity going on?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. GT-I9100, but I think it would be better to keep this topic more generic. I hope this question is relevant for other users, too. 3. No. It's just for paranoia's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, everything depends on the nature of the attacker. How determined are they, what resources have they, are they targeting you specifically?

If your concern is regular, non-targeted malware, you should be OK if you keep a clean SD card with a custom recovery manager on it, and use that to flash the ROM. It's important that you use that card for nothing else, and never have it in the device unless you're booting from it.

This means you need a clean device at some point to create that clean SD card, and later to update the ROM.

If you are facing a targeted attack from a well resourced attacker, things get more serious, and you'll probably need to switch to a "burner phone" model, where you throw the phone in the trash every few days and buy a new one.